# how to get sha-1 for android studio 3.5 message "nothing to show"

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1, firebase-console

i'm trying to get sha-1 form the right side of android studio gradle>android>tasks>signingReport but when i click on gradle in the right side of screen it showing a massage saying "Nothing to show"

this issue is showing in a certain app because when i tried to create a new project its working well

so please help me to solve it

i keep fined nothing to show only and its not possible to do refresh like old version my version is 3.5

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Click "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

[image]